# Howto Allow sharing access between VLAN

Tags: cisco, vlan

First thing first, I am not an Cisco expert. Using google,

I have managed to create simple very basic VLAN setup on Cisco 3750 switch and connect it Mikrotik Router board using trunk port. VLAN setup is as follows.

Mikrotik Router LAN Port = 10.0.0.0.1/24 [Connected with Cisco 3750 Port 1 , trunk]

Cisco 3750 Port 1 = Trunk, connected with Mikrotik

Port 2 = Vlan10 = 10.1.0.0/24 [User Group 1]

Port 3 = Vlan20 = 10.2.0.0/24 [User Group 2]

Port 3 = Vlan30 = 10.3.0.0/24 [FTP Media Sharing Server 1]

Port 4 = Vlan40 = 10.4.0.0/24 [FTP Media Sharing Server 2]

All users internet is working fine by mikrotik nat, and they are able to ping each other via there default gateways (via mikrotik gw).

This part is ok , Now the problem is if user groups wants to access FTP Media Sharing Servers, they have to pass via mikrotik router which puts load on Mikrotik (as the traffic volume reaches in GB which chocks the mikrotik port traffic as well]

Is there any way User Group can access FTP media sharing without going via mikrotik, they could somehow connect with FTP locally by switch port directly?

Comment: You need a layer 3 switch to do this.

Comment: Cisco 3750 is Layer 3 switch I guess.

Comment: Or create vlan interfaces on each Media Server for each network.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create L3 interfaces on your Cisco device (e. g. interface vlan 10, interface vlan 20).
2. Configure those interfaces' IP addresses as your default gateway on your hosts (or grant settings via DHCP).
3. Configure default route from Cisco switch to Mikrotik.
4. Configure static routes from Mikritik back to your subnets (10.1,2,3,4.0.0/24) via Cisco.

OR

3,4. Run OSPF between Cisco and Mikrotik and originate default from Mikrotik.

You'll only need one logical interface between Mikrotik and Cisco (e. g. port 1 vlan 50 ip address 10.0.0.1/30).

Local traffic will be routed at Cisco, and Internet traffic will be routed via Mikrotik.

Comment: Vlan are created in switch.
VLAN interfaces are made in Mikrotik. 
All users gets these interfaces interfaces ip as there default gateway via mikrotik dhcp.
switch ip is 10.0.0.10

So if I just add route in mikrotik like
10.1.0.0/24 route via 10.0.0.10
is enough?

Comment: No, you should create vlan interfaces on Cisco, so that Cisco will route local traffic as opposed to Mikrotik. Cisco will act as default gateway for your hosts, and Mikrotik will act as default gateway for Cisco.

Comment: & dhcp ? currently DHCP is running on the mikrotik.
Should I remove dhcp from the mikrotik and add DHCP role in Cisco also , according to the interfaces?

Comment: Actually you have options here. You can still run DHCP on Mikrotik if L2 connectivity between Cisco and Mikrotik remains in all VLANs, which is bad solution. You can run DHCP server on Cisco, which is OK. You can configure DHCP relay (aka ip helper) on Cisco's vlan interfaces so that Cisco will relay DHCP discovers to Mikrotik, which is also OK, scales better, but may require extra configuration.

Comment: What will happen to tagged traffic? as currently traffic is tagged on each vlan interface [port] then using trunk port this tagged traffic passes to mikrotik, where vlan interfaces are created and ip is assigned to each interface.

Comment: You're migrating to routing instead of switching. So you only need one interface between Cisco and Mikrotik. It doesn't matter would this interface be L3, or L2 with interface vlans, tagged or not. Traffic forwarding occurs based on IP routing table. You can allow one specific vlan between Cisco and Mikrotik. This vlan shouldn't be used for other purposes (Users, FTPs, etc.) Then you create interface vlan with this vlan number and are routing through it. Replacing switching with routing helps you to achieve what you're trying to achieve.